# How do different instance of the Python interpreter know about the same logger object?

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

I understand that the logging module implements loggers as singletons, but when you spawn a child process using the multiprocess module, how does the child "inherit" the same logger object?  A simple print statement in a Worker subprocess will show that the children are referencing the same logger object defined in the parent script if the same domain name is given when getLogger() is invoked in the child.

How can one instance of a Python interpreter access objects defined in another instance of a Python interpreter?  Is this being done through shared memory at the interpreter level?

Comment: This [link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py) might be helpful.

Comment: @hashcode55 - Thanks for the link, but I don't think that really helped me.  Without any context, I don't really know what's going on in that bit of code.  I have a decent understanding of how processes are spawned, but there are definitely gaps.